# how can i check how many versions of a docker image exists?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-registry

I want to get the number of tags/versions of a specific image i tried to use `docker inspectimage imagename` without the tag at the end but it takes the latest tag by default. How can I do this?

Comment: I am not really experienced with docker, but does the following help: `docker images | grep YOUR_IMAGE_NAME | wc -l`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

`docker images repo/imagename`

to see all the tags.

`docker images repo/imagename -q | wc -l`

will give you a count.

Comment: as mentioned, you can further refine via grep, so to ignore "latest" for instance, `docker images repo/imagename | grep -v latest

Comment: `uniq` can be added to the pipeline if you want the count of the different images rather than different tags.